# Samsung device not detected in ubuntu 13.04 all of sudden

Tags: samsung

Maybe my question is duplicate, but couldn't find the answer to work for me.

I've a samsung grand neo device which I am using for dev purpose.

It was working fine before, I could transfer file. Also I was using from android-studio once I configured **dev-rules.**

**/lib/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules**

```
  1 # samsung "04e8"                                                                                                                                  
  2 # others "18d1"                                                                                     
  3 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

and **/lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules**

```
  1 # usbfs-like devices                                                                                                                              
  2 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", \ MODE="0666"
```

**All of sudden,** I can't connect to the device, samsung device tells me **Connected as a media device** and MTP is checked on.

With `usb-devices` command, I can see the Samsung device,

```
...
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 18 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04e8 ProdID=6860 Rev=04.00
S:  Manufacturer=samsung
S:  Product=GT-I9060
S:  SerialNumber=4203bc03c21a7100
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=42 Prot=01 Driver=(none)

...
```

Also, result of `lsusb` gives me,

```
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
```

Comment: It sounds like ubuntu can see your device, but Android Studio (AS) can not. Did you update your version of AS?

Comment: "I can't connect" What exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

Shame, ubuntu restart worked fine.